# Ubuntu 14.04: Is there a way to reset python 2 and all dependencies to the factory setting?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a daily user of python 2 and after something (I am not sure but I believe it was pygments) was installed in my system I am not able to make the things work again as before. I have already lost two days! In particular, Anaconda2 installations is not working and a separated installation of spyder is not working as well.

Comment: I posted that question a while ago as well, but without any responses... http://askubuntu.com/q/675142/367990

Comment: I did not see it. Should I remove my question?

Comment: No, leave it. As mine has no answers, it can't be a duplicate target. So just leave it and hope that somebody might react on yours... :)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I mean you were able to make the things working without returning to the original installation?

Comment: I reinstalled when the next Ubuntu release came out instead of upgrading. Now I'm more careful not to upset my sensible Python... Actually there wasn't a severe problem, I just wanted to revert changes and start again from a fresh Python environment using virtualenvs.

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/734643/best-way-to-reinstall-ubuntu-14-04-without-deleting-my-files/734651#734651