# How do I reinstall Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1 without losing any data with only "/" and "SWAP"?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, root, ubuntu-studio, reinstall

I'd like to reinstall Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1, but I do not have the option to reinstall without destroying data. I would very much like to find a work-around to be able to keep my files and programs as I am not wanting to reinstall and redo all of the work I have done thus far. So is there a manual way to do this? If so it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/667143/how-to-reinstall-messed-up-14-04-without-losing-personal-data?rq=1

Comment: @db429 That might work