# dpkg error when trying to install libmemcached-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I was trying to install [libmemcached-dev](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/libmemcached-dev) for php, and I encountered an error:

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure
>   -a' to correct the problem.

Then I typed the `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, on the first try it gives an internal error and said that to report it. Then I tried it again(3-4 times): `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and my laptop always goes hang. And before it goes completely unresponsive, luckily the print screen works and here is the text:

```
[sudo] password for japjap:
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
japjap@laptop:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic (4.4.0-47.68) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
```

Anybody can help how I can solve this? I can't install anything.

First 20 lines of my `/etc/default/grub`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Update:

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            946M     0  946M   0% /dev
tmpfs           194M  6.2M  187M   4% /run
/dev/sda1       228G  8.9G  207G   5% /
tmpfs           966M  536K  965M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           966M     0  966M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           194M   64K  193M   1% /run/user/1000

lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   231G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

sudo blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="6416ac0d-4822-47aa-9035-a3fadf5033b2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="118168b7-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="437c42c7-26b8-4fb9-8fd7-10267ba9276a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="118168b7-05"

cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=6416ac0d-4822-47aa-9035-a3fadf5033b2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=437c42c7-26b8-4fb9-8fd7-10267ba9276a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Update:

```
free

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1976820      860788       80364      140768     1035668      766212
Swap:       2024444        2508     2021936

sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for japjap: 
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

Comment: In terminal, give me the answer to `uname -r`.

Comment: @heynnema `4.4.0-45-generic`

Answer (score 0):

You're having driver issues.

Boot with the `nomodeset` grub option.

To perform this from the **Grub Menu** hit `e` on the `ubuntu` option.  Then add the `nomodeset` parameter to the line that says, `quiet splash`.  After the edit hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Then edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and add this argument to the boot defaults.

**Change from:**

```
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:                                                                          
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'                                                                                          

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"                                                                                                            
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="$GRUB_TIMEOUT"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

**Change to:**

```
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:                                                                          
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'                                                                                          

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"                                                                                                            
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="$GRUB_TIMEOUT"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

The only line to be concerned with is the one highlighted in bold.

**Editor examples**

Use your favorite edit to edit the file.  These are examples to edit the file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

or

```
$ sudo pksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

After making the change update your `grub` with:

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo update-grub
```

This will resolve your laptop's lockup (due to hardware and drivers conflict) and allow you to complete the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command you're having problems with.

Comment: I tried this `info -f grub -n`, this is the result `info: option requires an argument -- 'n'
Try --help for more information.`

Comment: Should I restart my computer and press e ?

Comment: The block of information you are looking at is referring to contents in a file that needs to be changed.  You can edit the file with this command: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.  Save the changes and continue with what is provided in the answer.

Comment: Hello, it's been awhile and still hangs here is the screen shot http://imgur.com/a/Ylvem

Comment: @DumbQuestion Will you edit your question and show the content (at least the first 20 lines of your `/etc/default/grub` file?  I'm sure the problem lies there.

Comment: question updated

Comment: @L.D.James how did you get to conclusion that you did? Did I miss an important clue? Inquiring minds want to know :-) See my answer.

Comment: @heynnema By experiencing lockups on numerous computers that was resolved with the steps.  Also by assisting numerous others having lockups.  Outside the steps I provided (from as I mentioned, personal experience), the results wouldn't be total system lockup (an unresponsive computer that can only be recovered by rebooting).  There would be error messages that could be read and addressed and fixed.  The process of testing lots of things such as installing **aptitude** in lieu of using **apt** doesn't appear to address the actual on-responsive... locked up system. ..

Comment: ...the broken packages (to me) will cause errors with specific applications, not a total system's lockup as in the case with the user.  Also the image shows the lockup happens during the kernel update, whereas the programs he's trying to install are not in the immediate operation.

Comment: @DumbQuestion Did you run `sudo update-grub` after making the change you posted to your question?  Also if you are still getting the lockup, is it happening at the same places as the image in your original post".  If so, there is an alternate method that can be used to update your grub (where the problem is happening).

Comment: yes I use `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @DumbQuestion Now I need to know **if you are getting the same error message** or a different error message (when it locks up).  Also, when you used `sudo update-grub` did the update complete, then a reboot?  Your original image shows grub being updated when the computer locks up.

Comment: No I did not reboot it after I used `sudo update-grub`, I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then after that rebooted because it became very sluggish

Comment: @DumbQuestion The *grub* changes won't take effect until a reboot.  By the way, from your recent comment it appears that the "lockup/unresponsive" problem you were having has been cured.  I'm sure it's a result of the steps in the answer.  Now, will you perform the "configure-a" command,  update the text to your question before rebooting?  You couldn't do that before without an image.  Originally you were having problems with the updates.  After the system is sufficiently updated the newer drivers will provide more support for your hardware and you'll start to game better performance.

Comment: I tried the `configure -a` many times now, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Software Update failed, and left you partially updated. We'll try and fix this the short way...

From the Unity dashboard, start `Synaptic`. Go to the `edit` menu and choose `Fix broken packages`. Quit Synaptic.

**update**: If you can't use Synaptic, do this:

1. boot the system to the `GRUB` menu
2. choose `Advanced Options`
3. choose `Recovery mode`
4. choose `dpkg - fix broken packages`
5. when you return to the menu, choose `root access`
6. type `reboot`
7. once rebooted, open terminal, type `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
8. whether step 7 works or not, perform commands 1-5, below

From the Unity dashboard, start `terminal`. Enter the following commands, one at a time (best to use copy and paste):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I do not have synaptic only `synaptic_synaptic.png`

Comment: In terminal, type `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Comment: ps: if for some reason it errors when you try to install Synaptic, just go ahead with the other steps.

Comment: this image appears again http://imgur.com/a/XXb7W and my laptop goes very sluggish until I turn off it again.

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Edit your question to include the output, in terminal, of `df -h` and `lsblk`and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Were you able to run Synaptic and fix broken packages? Go ahead and try and run steps 2-5. Please answer **all** my questions, and give **all** requested output. Report back.

Comment: my question has been updated, and I can't install Synaptic this is the error: `dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with that info. All of it looks fine, except your swap is a little small. You forgot to tell me how much RAM you have (type `free` in terminal), and whether steps 2-5 worked for you. If they don't, we'll have to try something else.

Comment: I updated my question, step 2 does not work.

Comment: Please see the **update** in my answer on what to do next.

Comment: I tried rebooting to grub menu but, the only appearing is `Grub loading...` then I held `shift` but it returns to normal state.

Comment: Don't you normally see the GRUB menu when you turn on the computer? If not, try holding down EITHER the LEFT SHIFT key, or the ESC key, during boot and you should see it. Then use the UP/DOWN arrow keys to select ADVANCED OPTIONS, then hit the ENTER key.

Comment: I tried left shift key and I only saw the `Grub loading` then after that it continued to start at normal state no Grub menu at all.

Comment: Did you try the ESC key?

Comment: yes, I tried `autoremove` part, did not work, `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. `

Comment: You're still not being clear on if you see the normal GRUB menu at boot time... either normally, or by holding down LEFT SHIFT key, or by tapping the ESC key a few times at boot time. We need to complete step 4 in my updated instructions. If we can't get that done, I can't help any further.

Comment: Yes it works, it says that Killed then I pressed enter then I went back to grub menu and rebooted it.

Comment: Again, you're not being clear. Were you able to do step 4? What does "that Killed" mean? What happened at step 7? If step 7 worked, did you do the 5 `sudo apt-get` commands? Please be concise.

Comment: Yes, I did step 4, the "Killed" is appeared after a long time of  updates that step 4 do. Step 7 did not worked.

Comment: @LDJames I'm out of ideas. Somebody with more expertise on dpkg and apt-get  will be required to help more. Can you help?

Comment: Should I reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, reinstall. Sorry we couldn't repair it any other way. We tried!

Comment: How to reinstall? I can't find this link useful https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation, because this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuInstaller that indicates in the first link is broken.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/667143/how-to-reinstall-messed-up-14-04-without-losing-personal-data