# Does installing Ubuntu 16.04 in 10.04 system erases anything?

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu 16.04, I already have 10.04,so is there a chance of my files being lost in installing Ubuntu 16.04 over 10.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall messed-up 14.04 without losing personal data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667143/how-to-reinstall-messed-up-14-04-without-losing-personal-data) and [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: Which files do you mean? If they're your personal data files (photos, music, documents, etc) back them up on external storage, verify the backup, and do a clean install after first checking out how a live USB works on your machine. Since you are on 10.04, it's possible that your machine may not be able to run 16.04.

Comment: no i was using 12.04 but it was lost somehow. So i installed 10.04, also i would like to know why my flash drive is showing it is not a bootable one when booted? i pasted ubuntu-16.04.5-server-i386.iso into the drive as said in  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick. Then booted it , but of no use. help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is a chance of data loss - installing and upgrading any computer Operating System is *inherently risky*.

Developers try to minimize those risks and preserve your data, but cannot predict every possible problem.

ALWAYS back up your data before starting an OS install or upgrade.

Comment: thanks ! i moved files to harddisk. I left one or two non-important files in the user folder after installation it was removed!

Answer (score 0):

1. It's always important to backup your data just to be safe.
2. You could partition your internal hard disk one partition specifically for the os and programs the other for personal files like documents. In the event you want to change or upgrade the OS you'll only be installing on the OS-partition. you won't be tampering with the other partition thus decreasing the possibility of losing your personal data.